# Still/DSLR Camera with ROS

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use a Canon EOS M for computer vision in ROS. I have experience using webcams with ROS, and I have not had any trouble with webcams. I am not sure how to control the Canon from ROS. I would like to be able to set the cameras parameters such as white balance, focus, etc... and be able to program it to take pictures at precise moments. Any suggestions on how to make this work? I have hear about gphoto, but I haven't been able to get that to work.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/186941/still/dslr-camera-with-ros/) by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2014-07-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone that comes across this post again I am able to control the dslr camera using libgphoto2. There is an excellent tutorial here

http://sepharads.blogspot.com/2011/11/camera-tethered-capturing-using.html

I was also able to take what was needed for my implementation from the libgphoto2 examples that was not included in the tutorial. The only tricky part was linking both gphoto2 and gphoto2_port in cmakelists.txt; originally, I only linked gphoto2. Also, I was not able to get libgphoto 2.5.x to compile, and I had to revert to libgphoto2 2.4.x to make everything work.

---

Originally posted by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) with karma: 280 on 2014-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about ROS packages but you could definitely program something in Python and make it as a ROS node.
It is possible to control a DSLR using python and this:

http://magiclantern.wikia.com/wiki/Remote_control_with_PTP_and_Python

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ralff](https://answers.ros.org/users/11841/ralff/) on 2014-09-03**:
This would probably would have worked, but I needed a c or c++ implementation